# i18n - Translate only specific fields

Tags: i18n-l10n

Sorry if my question seams trivial, but I wonder if it is actually possible.

In Drupal 7, with the i18n module I can easily translate a content entry, but from this, I feel like it creates a fork of my language source content. So my update on the source language are no longer reflected on the translated content.

Example:
I have a content defined as an image plus a text field.
I want only the text field to be translated, not the image. Can I do that?

I have the situation with a website with many languages, I would prefer if I don't need to update all the images for each language whenever I want to update the image.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so is by configuring the multilingual parameter of your node type as "Enabled, with field translation".

The steps :

- enable the module i18n_fields
- edit your node type
- go to publishing options tab
- set Multilingual support => "Enabled, with field translation"

This way, there will be only one node for all the translation of your node (e.g.: node/534) and only the translatable fields will change between language.

You need to then define which fields you want to translate :

- in the content type, go to manage fields tab
- choose the field and edit
- check the box "Field translation" at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but perhaps the [Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module is what you want to be looking at?